# Is there in library in Apache PySpark to convert html to pdf?

Tags: html, pdf, pyspark, pdf-generation, pyspark-pandas

I'm trying to use a PySpark notebook in Microsoft Azure Synapse to convert an HTML string to a pdf. I have found multiple library’s such as **"weasyprint"**, **"wkhtmltopdf"**, **"wkhtml2pdf"**, and **"pdfkit"** that work in python but aren't available in PySpark.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

example code:

```html
    <h2> why cant i get this to work </h2>
    <p> I am not entirely sure this is possible to do in PySpark</p>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th> test1 </th>
        <th> test2 </th>
     </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>42</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: I think you can add those libraries in the SparkContext and then create a UDF that will be convert HTML to PDF using specified library. Take a look at `pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile`